# System.arraycopy() equivalent in C, C++ or Objective-C

Tags: java, c++, objective-c, c

I am porting an android app (java) to ios app. A part of it is real time display graph.

I use this code to insert value to index 0 off array:

```
public double[] points;
.....
//Clear array value at first index
System.arraycopy(points, 0, points, 1, points.length - 1);
//Add new value to first index
points[0] = sample;
```

Have some question about this but not useful for my case.

I can use NSMutableArray and NSNumber to get the result but it require much more code and then CPU

Comment: Pick **a** target language please.

Comment: I would use `std::vector` in place of your array and use `std::vector::insert()`.

Comment: This might be useful: [C and C++ equivalent to Java's System.arraycopy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844198/c-equivalent-to-javas-system-arraycopy)

Comment: @WhozCraig I can use what ever if it can solve my problem, c, c++ and objective-c can use with Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C one would initially do:

```
size_t n_points = 512;
double *points = calloc(512, sizeof(double));
```

---

Then the logic would be:

```
memmove(points + 1, points, n_points - 1);
*points = sample;
```

---

Though even better would be to use a ring buffer - so instead of moving the values around the buffer, just move the index that is considered the beginning:

```
size_t n_points = 512;
double *points = calloc(512, sizeof(double));
ssize_t beginning = 0;
```

---

```
if (--beginning < 0) {
    beginning += n_points;
}
points[beginning] = sample;
```

And then in drawing code:

```
ssize_t idx, i;
for (idx = beginning, i = 0;
     i < n_points;
     i ++, idx = (idx + 1) % n_points)
{
    // i runs from 0 ... n_points - 1
    set_pixel(i, points[idx], black);
}
```

Comment: I edit your code like below and it work fine:     #define MAXPOINTS 200;
    double points[MAXPOINTS];
    memmove(points + 1, points, MAXPOINTS - 1);
    points[0] = sample;
    
    And i don;t know why some people downvote me!

Comment: A couple of cautions: If you use calloc() or malloc() to create a memory buffer yourself, ARC doesn't release it for you. You must be sure to call free() when you are done with the buffer. Also, a ring buffer overwrites itself and the oldest values are lost. Finally, a ring buffer like this is fixed in size. You can't decide later to make it bigger (well, you could by adding extra logic and a realloc call, but that's another story.)

Comment: If you're ok working with pointers in C and managing the memory yourself, and don't need your buffer to resize dynamically then this approach is fine, and should be faster than dealing with NSArrays in Objective-C.

Comment: @DuncanC the `double[]` in Java is not resizeable either - you need to allocate a new array and copy the contents there.

Answer (score 0):

In **C++** I would be tempted to use a `std::vector` in place of your `Java` array:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    struct point
    {
        int x, y;
        point(int x, int y): x(x), y(y) {}
    };

    std::vector<point> points;

    point sample {2, 7};

    points.insert(points.begin(), sample); // insert at beginning
    points.insert(points.begin(), {9, 3});
    points.insert(points.begin(), {4, 8});

    points.push_back(sample); // insert at end

    for(auto p: points)
        std::cout << "{" << p.x << ", " << p.y << "}" << '\n';
}
```

If you do a **lot** if inserting at the beginning a [`std::deque`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/) might be worth looking at.

**Reference:** [How a std::vector works](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Answer (score 0):

In Obective-C you can use the NSMutableArray method to insert an item at index 0.

```
 - (void)insertObject:(id)anObject atIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

Comment: As i mention from beginning, I have try NSMutableArray but it not good for cpu

Comment: What does "it not good for CPU" mean? Have you implemented the equivalent, found that it is too slow, profiled it, and determined that NSArray `insertObject:atIndex:` is the method that is taking all the extra time?

Comment: @Duncan C: Thank for your answer, but Antti Haapala work for me and it use only  4 line of code and fast.

Comment: @DzungPV, If you're going to use manually allocated memory and C style arrays, fine. That approach is about as far away from Java's garbage collected, no-pointers style as you can get without writing assembler however.  You also need to be aware that the memory management is up to you. You have to free the buffer  (points in this example) when you are done with it or you will cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick Google search it looks like System.arrayCopy() copies a subset of a source array into a destination array.

It sounds like you want your new array to be an NSMutableArray, and want to use 
`- insertObjects:atIndexes:`. That method takes an NSIndexSet as input. You can use the NSIndexSet method `indexSetWithIndexesInRange` to create an index set from a range of indexes.